# Error compiling AMD with typescript

Tags: compiler-construction, requirejs, typescript, amd, openlayers-3

I am currently encountering a problem with my typescript compilation.

I am using the last version on [OpenLayers](http://ol3js.org) (3.0.0 Beta 1) and I try to integrate it into my AMD modules. I precise that I am not really familiar with the AMD mechanism and typescript.

To manage my map, created thanks to OpenLayers3, i am creating a new module :

**OlMap.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../_import.ts" />

import ol = require('ol');

/*
*   Custom class used to wrap the OpenLayers Map class.
*   This is used to extend the functionnalities (i.e. controls)
*   Defined following the chaining method pattern.
*
*   @module OlMap
*   @class
*/
class OlMap {
      // My code here
}
```

To make easier the use of OpenLayers3 (that is not AMD), i created a **definition file** called **ol3.d.ts** that is referenced into my _import.ts

My problem is that when i try to compile this, i am getting the error :

```
OlMap.ts<3.1> error TS2071: Unable to resolve external module ''ol''
OlMap.ts<3.1> error TS2072: Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.
```

The compile file looks like :

```
/// <reference path="../_import.ts" />
define(["require", "exports", 'ol'], function(require, exports, __ol__) {
    var ol = 'ol';
```

But it should be more like :

```
/// <reference path="../_import.ts" />
define(["require", "exports", 'ol'], function(require, exports, __ol__) {
    var ol = __ol__;
```

If i manually edit the javascript file generated like the previous code (var ol = __ ol__;) i have no dependencies problems, but the generated file creates errors due to the compilation error.

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Edit :
I am **not** integrating the OpenLayer javascript file into the HTML. OpenLayer is not an AMD library so, i am using the RequireJS's Shim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare it as an externally loaded module. i.e:

```
declare module 'ol'{
    var openlayers:any;
    export = openlayers;
}

import ol = require('ol');


class OlMap {
      // My code here
}
```

Which generates:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'ol'], function(require, exports, __ol__) {
    var ol = __ol__;

    var OlMap = (function () {
        function OlMap() {
        }
        return OlMap;
    })();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already defined the new version of OpenLayers (inspired by the https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped project) with a file **.d.ts**. After a few tests, my code is working as well as expected but the error definitely comes from the tsc's build.

I don't know why, but when i put the declaration in a separated file (my definition file is well referenced) **tsc** fails.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are including the openLayers3's JS file explicitly in your index.html (i.e. not using requireJS). In that case, you can solve the problem by creating a file with the name `ol.ts` in the root folder (where `require` looks for it) and puting the following in it:

```js
/// <reference path="./path/to/ol.d.ts" />

export = ol;
```

This should re-exporte the OpenLayers's `window.ol` object in an AMD friendly way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, i am trying to remove the OpenLayers3 js file from the index.html and to use RequireJS instead.

With the file links into the HTML, that was working, but that is a problem to work further

Comment: @AdrienSaunier You still may want to keep the file around to satisfy Typescript while  allowing require/r.js to handle the external libraries via shims.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution.

Instead of loading the OL3 from the concerned AMD module, i tried to load it at the application bootstrap as i did for AngularJS and jQuery. 
The shim mechanism looks working.

Nevertheless, i still don't know why the Typescript builder refused to compile my application.
Thanks for your help.